# How to get icon from OpenWeatherMap

Tags: java, android, imageview, openweathermap

I want to get openweathermap icon. https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions and http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1 icon is string value. I create imageView but i dont it

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
            String text = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);



            Factory.getInstance().havaModel(text,APPID_KEY).enqueue(new Callback<HavaModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<HavaModel> call, Response<HavaModel> response) {
                    textView.setText(Float.toString((float) (response.body().main.temp-273.15)));
                    textView2.setText(Float.toString(response.body().coord.lon));
                    textView3.setText(Integer.toString(response.body().main.humidity));
                    textView4.setText(response.body().name);
                    imageView.getResources()



                }
```

[image]

Thank you very much.
Your advice important for me

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for the icons is here.

http://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

You'll get the icon code from the object that your JSON call returns,
As given in your question, and then use that to construct a url which points to the icon,

```
String iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";
```

Also you can use an Image Loading Library to load the image into your ImageView - For eg:- Using [Picasso Image Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) -

Add this inside your build.gradle file -

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

And then use below code to load the image inside your ImageView -

```
Picasso.with(context).load(iconUrl).into(imageView);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -0.13,
        "lat": 51.51
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10n"
        }
    ],
```

From the above json you can get the icon Id and use the following url to load the images
http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10n.png

link to official Documentation on the same is [here](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions)

Comment: That link is a sample one and it is working absolutely fine. Please give it a try once again.